# initialize bean with new instance of the object

Tags: java, spring

Originally I initialized object like this

```
Stage stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport())
```

Where

```
stage -> com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage
screenViewport -> com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport
```

Then I decided to use `spring`.
I added field to my object (which is `@component`)

```
@Autowired
private Stage stage
```

And added in `xml`

```
<bean id="stage"
        class="com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage">
    <constructor-arg type="com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport"
        value="#{ new com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport() }"/>
</bean>
```

But I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationMain': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'screen': Error creating bean with name 'applicationMenuScreen': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stage': Error creating bean with name 'stage' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stage' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationMenuScreen': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stage': Error creating bean with name 'stage' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stage' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stage' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
```

What is the proper way to initalize with `new ScreenViewport()` as a parameter?

Comment: couldn't you just create a new bean `screenViewport` of type `ScreenViewport` and pass that bean into the value?

Comment: Well I think I can but I'd like to do it somehow directly

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a bean `screenViewPort` with scope `prototype`.
See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

```
<bean id="stage"
      class="com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage">
    <property name="screenViewPort" ref="screenViewPort" />
</bean>

<bean id="screenViewPort" scope="prototype"
      class="com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport" />
```

Comment: Well...It seems without declaring bean I cannot do it in the end. Well fair enough as it might need `ScreenViewport` in the scope of `Spring` container.

Comment: When you do not want to always get a new instance of ScreenViewport just leave the scope for this bean as singleton is standard scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this. Since you're using the `@Autowired` annotation, use the `@Value` annotation.

To illustrate it's use in your example, you would do something like this:

```
@Component
public class Stage {
    @Autowired
    public Stage(ScreenViewport screenViewport){
        // do stuff
    }
}

@Component
public class ScreenViewport {
    public ScreenViewport(@Value("#{some expression here}") String foo){
         // do even more stuff
    }
}
```

There is a lot more information in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based). If you also need to have several instances of `ScreenViewport`, look into [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: I don't have access to `Stage` or `ScreenViewport` classes